# C++ How to display Unicode wstring as Number in Unicode format

Tags: c++, unicode, cout, wstring

I have a std::wstring like that:

```
std::wstring mystr = L"abc\U0000FFFF\U0000000A\U00000061\U00000010de";
```

I want to print it out to the console where it should look like that:

```
abc\U0000FFFF\U0000000A\U00000061\U00000010de
```

When I try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    char16_t* ctest = &c[i];
    std::cout << *ctest<< " ";
}
```

the result is

```
61 62 63 ffff a 61 10 64 65
```

How can I get the my desired output?

Comment: Use double backslashes in your string literal

Comment: What should be stored in `mystr`?  Your _for loop_ implies that you want exactly 9 wide characters.  Your _desired output_ implies that you want many more than 9 characters.  Perhaps you want your program to know how each character was encoded in your source code?

Comment: mystr contains 9 characters some in unicode (\U00....), some in characters(a,b,c) I want to print those 9 characters exactly like I read them into my wstring.

Comment: _"some in unicode..."_.  You are mistaken.  A character does not know _how you described its value_ in your source code.  `wchar_t{'a'}` and `wchar_t{'\U00000061'}` and `wchar_t{97}` are all the same character.  If you need to display what the values look like in your source code, you will need to store that information separately.

Comment: `std::wstring mystr = L"abc\\U0000FFFF\\U0000000A\\U00000061\\U00000010de";`

Comment: Or: `std::wstring mystr = LR"(abc\U0000FFFF\U0000000A\U00000061\U00000010de)";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inspect each character as you output it.  If it's in the printable ASCII range, output it as a char; otherwise output it as a hex sequence.

```
    std::wstring mystr = L"abc\U0000FFFF\U0000000A\U00000061\U00000010de";
    for (int i = 0;  i < mystr.size();  ++i)
    {
        if (mystr[i] >= 0x20 && mystr[i] < 0xff)
            cout << (char)mystr[i];
        else
            cout << "\\U" << std::setfill('0') << std::right << std::setw(8) << std::hex << mystr[i];
    }
```

https://ideone.com/ucepKy

The output differs from your desired output because you have the character "a" in there twice, once as a single character and once as a hex escape sequence.  Once the string is compiled, there's no way to tell the difference between the two.

Comment: This will not produce the requested output, as `\U0000000A`, `\U00000061`, and `\U00000010` are characters in the ASCII range.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I said "printable" ASCII range, and a quick look at the code will show how I define it.  And I already explained why `\U00000061` isn't going to be possible - I'm not here to solve unsolvable problems.  The link I provided is to an example program using this exact code, you can see the output yourself.

Comment: If you want to detect "printable" characters, consider using `std::isprint()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau about `std::isprint`: ["The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint)  I think that would be a problem for `'\U0000FFFF'`.

Comment: [`std::iswprint()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswprint), then

Comment: @RemyLebeau I forgot about `iswprint` but I don't think it matters, because the question uses `cout` and not `wcout`.  To be honest the question isn't really well formed anyway.